# Using postcss-each to define classes in a tailwind layer

Tags: tailwind-css, postcss

I would like to create a set of utilities for controlling spacing using css clamp. The spacing that I would like to use is reused throughout the website I'm building but how it is used varies. For example:

- Element A needs spacing inner top of 96px
- Element B needs spacing inner top and bottom of 96px
- Element C needs spacing inner bottom of 96px

I'm trying to achieve this using postcss-each like this:

```
:root {
  --s-24: clamp(15px, 1.7vw, 24px);
  --s-32: clamp(24px, 2.22vw, 32px);
  --s-44: clamp(12px, 22vw, 44px);
  --s-52: clamp(30px, 3.61vw, 52px);
  --s-56: clamp(30px, 2.9vw, 56px);
  --s-74: clamp(50px, 3.85vw, 74px);
  --s-96: clamp(35px, 6.7vw, 96px);
  --s-101: clamp(60px, 7.06vw, 101.72px);
  --s-106: clamp(50px, 7.36vw, 106px);
  --s-115: clamp(35px, 6vw, 115px);
}
@layer utilities {
  @each $s in (24, 32, 44, 52, 56, 74, 96, 101, 106, 115) {
    .u-soy-$(s) {
      margin-top: var(--s-$(s));
      margin-bottom: var(--s-$(s));
    }

    .u-sot-$(s) {
      margin-top: var(--s-$(s));
    }

    .u-sob-$(s) {
      margin-bottom: var(--s-$(s));
    }

    .u-siy-$(s) {
      padding-top: var(--s-$(s));
      padding-bottom: var(--s-$(s));
    }

    .u-sit-$(s) {
      padding-top: var(--s-$(s));
    }

    .u-sib-$(s) {
      padding-bottom: var(--s-$(s));
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to use the code above in another css file like this `@apply u-sot-96;` I'm getting an error.

> The `u-sot-96` class does not exist. If `u-sot-96` is a custom class, make sure it is defined within a `@layer` directive.

My question is this, is what I'm trying to achieve possible using a loop, or should I define each class separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider checking that `postcss-each` runs before Tailwind, by defining it before Tailwind in the PostCSS configuration, like:

```js
plugins: {
  'postcss-each': {},
  tailwindcss: {},
},
```

Otherwise, you could look at adding the spacing values in Tailwind and not using `postcss-each` altogether, like:

```js
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      // Evaluates to an object like
      // spacing: {
      //   's-24': 'var(--s-24)',
      //   's-32': 'var(--s-32)',
      //   …
      spacing: Object.fromEntries(
        [24, 32, 44, 52, 56, 74, 96, 101, 106, 115].map(
          value => [`s-${value}`, `var(--s-${value})`]
        ),
      )
    },
  },
}
```

```css
:root {
  --s-24: clamp(15px, 1.7vw, 24px);
  --s-32: clamp(24px, 2.22vw, 32px);
  --s-44: clamp(12px, 22vw, 44px);
  --s-52: clamp(30px, 3.61vw, 52px);
  --s-56: clamp(30px, 2.9vw, 56px);
  --s-74: clamp(50px, 3.85vw, 74px);
  --s-96: clamp(35px, 6.7vw, 96px);
  --s-101: clamp(60px, 7.06vw, 101.72px);
  --s-106: clamp(50px, 7.36vw, 106px);
  --s-115: clamp(35px, 6vw, 115px);
}
```

Then you could use the Tailwind `padding`, `margin`, etc utilities like:

```html
<div class="my-s-24">…</div>
<div class="pb-s-32">…</div>
```

```css
.my-selector {
  @apply mt-s-74;
}

.my-other-selector {
  @apply py-s-96;
}
```

And so on.

Comment: Adding the spacing values works great, thank you!